# Listing sequence with rules

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, sequence

How would one go about listing all sequences `S` length 10 made up of a combination of `a's` and `b's`, where there are either at least 5 consecutive `a's` or 5 consecutive `b's`.
Example sequences are:

```
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaabbbba
bbaaaaaaab
```

etc but not

```
aaaaabbbbb
```

Comment: @Kuba it is EITHER a or b, so it is basically a xor b (5 a's and b's therefore not allowed consecutively)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[dionys](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/20144/dionys) [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132475/29734) is the straight-forward way of generating all the lists and pruning down to the ones you want. Here's a method that generates *only* those ones you want, which means it will work much faster for longer lists.  Here is an example for a smaller length list (length 6 with one `aaa` or one `bbb`).

First generate all integer partitions of 6 that include one 3:

```
partitions = Cases[IntegerPartitions[6], {a_ /; a >= 3, ___?(# != 3 &)}]
(* {{6}, {5, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 1, 1, 1}} *)
```

Now, permute each one of these:

```
allPartitions = Flatten[Permutations /@ partitions, 1]
(* {{6}, {5, 1}, {1, 5}, {4, 2}, {2, 4}, {4, 1, 1}, {1, 4, 1}, {1, 1, 4},
    {3, 2, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {2, 3, 1}, {2, 1, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, 
    {3, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 3, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 3}} *)
```

Now, this list gives a list of the number of `a`'s and `b`'s, alternating. To make the lists, we do:

```
halfList = Flatten@Module[{i = 0}, 
  Replace[#, x_ :> ConstantArray[If[EvenQ[i++], "a", "b"], {x}], 1]
 ] & /@ allPartitions
(* {{a, a, a, a, a, a}, {a, a, a, a, a, b}, {a, b, b, b, b, b},
    {a, a, a, a, b, b}, {a, a, b, b, b, b}, {a, a, a, a, b, a},
    {a, b, b, b, b, a}, {a, b, a, a, a, a}, {a, a, a, b, b, a},
    {a, a, a, b, a, a}, {a, a, b, b, b, a}, {a, a, b, a, a, a},
    {a, b, b, b, a, a}, {a, b, b, a, a, a}, {a, a, a, b, a, b},
    {a, b, b, b, a, b}, {a, b, a, a, a, b}, {a, b, a, b, b, b}} *)
```

This is exactly *half* of the tuples. To get the other half, just switch `a` and `b`:

```
result = Join[halfList, halfList /. {"a" -> "b", "b" -> "a"}];
Multicolumn[result, 3]
```

[image]

---

Wrapping this all up in a function:

```
sequences[n_?EvenQ] := 
  Join[#, # /. {"a" -> "b", "b" -> "a"}] &@Module[{m = n/2, partitions},
    partitions = Cases[IntegerPartitions[n], {x_ /; x >= m, ___?(# != m &)}];
    partitions = Flatten[Permutations /@ partitions, 1];
    Flatten@Module[{i = 0},
      Replace[#, x_ :> ConstantArray[If[EvenQ[i++], "a", "b"], {x}], 1]
     ] & /@ partitions
   ]
```

Comment: I am attempting to clean up some of the code, like the part where it generates the alternating tables of `a`'s and `b`'s.

Comment: @ChrisGeorgiou. Please see edit. I missed two of them, I think.  I have also wrapped everything into a function.

Answer (score 5):

```
Module[{full, a5, b5, excl},
 full = Tuples[{a, b}, 10];
 a5 = Cases[full, {___, a, a, a, a, a, ___}];
 b5 = Cases[full, {___, b, b, b, b, b, ___}];
 excl = Cases[Union[a5, b5], Except[{a, a, a, a, a, b, b, b, b, b}]];
 Cases[excl, Except[{b, b, b, b, b, a, a, a, a, a}]]]

(*{{a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a}, {a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, b},
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, \
{<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}, {<<10>>}}*)
```

Comment: thanks, but this gives 221 outputs (if im not wrong?) how would it give an odd number of outputs if the ordering is symmetric?

Comment: You probably want to exclude bbbbbaaaaa too

Answer (score 3):

```
r = Cases[
   Tuples[{"a", "b"}, 
    10], {___, 
     Sequence @@ Table["a", 5], ___} | {{___, 
      Sequence @@ Table["b", 5], ___}}];
f = DeleteCases[r, 
   Table["a", 5]~Join~Table["b", 5] | 
    Table["b", 5]~Join~Table["a", 5]];
Grid[Partition[StringJoin /@ f, 10]]
```

[image]

**Note:** march pointed my clearly erroneous initial answer. I hope I have corrected this.

Comment: I was assuming that sequences like "abababbbbb" are allowed. @ChrisGeorgiou, can you clarify? Because if only sequences of the type you've written in your post are allowed, ubdqn's answer is very nice.

Comment: @march my stupid blunder! I will delete

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different approach:

We can consider a stripe of characters of the length from 5 to 10 and then shift in a band of 10 placeholders, surrounding by all possible tuples of other characters. Also, note that we should surround this stripe by alternative characters and only then consider tuples for the remaining placeholders on the left and on the right (depending on the shift), since we don't want to create a sequence of n+1 characters. Thus we eliminate almost all redundancies.

```
halfList[l_, nmin_] :=
  Flatten[Map[Flatten, ({n} \[Function]
       (stripe[ft_, lt_, pos_] :=
         Flatten@Join[
           If[pos > 2, {ft}, {Nothing}],
           If[pos > 1, {"b"}, {Nothing}],
           Table["a", n],
           If[pos < l - n + 1, {"b"}, {Nothing}],
           If[pos < l - n, {lt}, {Nothing}]
           ];
        stripeList[pos_] := 
         Outer[stripe[#1, #2, pos] &, 
          Tuples[{"a", "b"}, Max[0, pos - 2]], 
          Tuples[{"a", "b"}, Max[0, l - n - pos]], 1];
        shiftedList = stripeList /@ Range[1, l - n + 1]
        )) /@ Range[nmin, l - 1], {-2}], 3];

Cases[StringJoin @@@ halfList[10, 5], Except["aaaaabbbbb"]]
```

This only does half of the list, and the `Flatten` piece is sloppy, but the performance is actually quite decent, on par if not better than march's [code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132477/44141). I might improve it later on.